# Media Codec | Android | Video Decoding native crash

Tags: android, video, opengl-es-2.0, samsung-mobile, android-mediacodec

Some background: My app allows a user to preview multiple videos on the screen using OpenGL and MediaCodec APIs starting from API 16 and above. The videos are all .mp4 files.

I am experiencing a similar crash [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22392399/for-fadden-is-this-the-same-android-mediacodec-crash) after I have decoded the videos on my surfaces. But mine is specific to **Samsung Devices**

**Crash Line:**

A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 11685 (MediaCodec_loop)

**LogCat Output:**

```
02-09 18:56:41.819    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-09 18:56:41.819    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? Build fingerprint: 'samsung/m0zs/m0:4.1.2/JZO54K/I9300ZSEMK2:user/release-keys'
02-09 18:56:41.819    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? pid: 16880, tid: 17266, name: MediaCodec_loop  >>> com.flambestudios.picplaypost <<<
02-09 18:56:41.819    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? r0 00000000  r1 00000000  r2 00008210  r3 00000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? r4 00000000  r5 00000000  r6 00000000  r7 00000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? r8 00000000  r9 64a44e80  sl 00000000  fp 00000001
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? ip 00000000  sp 64a44d20  lr 00000000  pc 4010e55c  cpsr 20000010
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d0  443b400046180400  d1  44a6a00000000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d2  0000053500000000  d3  00000000000002ed
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d4  0000000000000000  d5  000002ed0073e20e
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d6  00000535443b4000  d7  00002601443b4000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d8  000000003f800000  d9  4049000000000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d10 4049000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d16 0000000000000001  d17 0000000000000000
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d18 000000000073bffb  d19 000000000073cf5c
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d20 000000000073bf1b  d21 0020002000200820
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d22 000000000073f44f  d23 000000000073bd24
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d24 0820082008200820  d25 0020002000200820
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d26 0020002000200020  d27 0020002000200820
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d28 0020002000200020  d29 000000000073f41e
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? d30 0820082008200020  d31 0020002000200020
02-09 18:56:42.084    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? scr 80000013
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? backtrace:
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #00  pc 0000e55c  /system/lib/libc.so (memset+148)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #01  pc 0000144c  /system/lib/libSEC_OMX_Core.so (SEC_OMX_Component_Unregister+16)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #02  pc 00001828  /system/lib/libSEC_OMX_Core.so (SEC_OMX_DeInit+44)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #03  pc 00000ae7  /system/lib/libstagefrighthw.so (android::SECOMXPlugin::~SECOMXPlugin()+18)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #04  pc 00000b0d  /system/lib/libstagefrighthw.so (android::SECOMXPlugin::~SECOMXPlugin()+4)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #05  pc 0000c157  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (android::OMXMaster::clearPlugins()+58)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #06  pc 0000c189  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (android::OMXMaster::~OMXMaster()+12)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #07  pc 0000c1d1  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (android::OMXMaster::~OMXMaster()+4)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #08  pc 0000aec3  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (android::OMX::~OMX()+38)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #09  pc 0000af4d  /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (android::OMX::~OMX()+4)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #10  pc 0000ef11  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+40)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #11  pc 0005399b  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::sp<android::MPEG2PSExtractor::Track>::~sp()+18)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #12  pc 000810e3  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MuxOMX::~MuxOMX()+30)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #13  pc 00081125  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MuxOMX::~MuxOMX()+4)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #14  pc 0000ef11  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+40)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #15  pc 00055e7f  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ACodec::LoadedState::onShutdown(bool)+130)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #16  pc 00056d27  /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::ACodec::LoadedState::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+106)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #17  pc 000066bd  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHierarchicalStateMachine::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+80)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #18  pc 00007471  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooperRoster::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+188)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #19  pc 00006d25  /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+204)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #20  pc 0001103b  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+94)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #21  pc 00010bb5  /system/lib/libutils.so
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #22  pc 00012e00  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+48)
02-09 18:56:42.099    1902-1902/? I/DEBUG? #23  pc 00012558  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+172)
```

The problem specifically arises, when I try to decode more than 2 video files on  Galaxy S3 (2 videos play just fine).

I've tested the same code on HTC OneX(4.1.x) & LG Nexus4 (4.2.x) and they play even 6 videos at a time without an issue.

Any ideas what the issue is ?

**EDIT # 1**

The problem is mainly with software codecs, the codecs I get for my mime-type are 3 hardware and 1 software namely, OMX.SEC.avc.dec, OMX.SEC.avcdec, OMX.SEC.AVC.Decoder & OMX.google.h264.decoder respectively. OMX.SEC.avc.dec only manages to decode 1 video and other videos get OMX.google.h264.decoder as their decoder (other 2 are useless in my case).

I've also tested the app on Nexus5(Lollipop), Xiaomi Mi3(KitKat) & Galaxy S4(KitKat) with absolutely no issue, as these devices manage to successfully allocate 6 hardware codecs for decoding.

Comment: All devices have a limit on the number of videos that can be decoded simultaneously by the hardware codec (either by instance count or by total bandwidth required). Attempting to do more can result in a failure to configure, or in the use of a software fallback. Sounds like you hit a bug here. There is no mandated behavior, and I don't know what the status of CTS tests on multiple simultaneous decoding is (there weren't any in 4.3, don't think there were in 4.4, no idea about 5.0). In any event, this should be reported on http://b.android.com/, and represented in CTS.

Comment: I've updated my question with more info and tests i've carried. Another problem I am facing is that, this fatal signal crashes my app, and there is nothing I can do about it, tried try-catching it to no success. Is there a way to atleast catch this exception and show some message to user ?

Comment: This is a native crash (looks like an attempt to memset a null pointer) way down in the SEC OMX code when shutting a decoder down. It's not an exception; there's no way to catch it. Somebody with a deep understanding of this part of the system might be able to suggest a way to work around it.

Comment: *some more info*, I've found after several tests that if I play 5 videos simultaneously, the first 4 decoders get instance of OMX.SEC.avc.dec codec and 5th gets OMX.google.h264.decoder codec. Everything plays smoothly. But if I play 6 videos (app's upper bound requirement) simultaneously and create 2 instances of OMX.google.h264.decoder codec for 5th n 6th video, this fatal signal comes again after the videos have finished playing. Any wild guesses @fadden ? (test carried on Galaxy S3)

Comment: Sounds like a GS3 bug. I don't have any ideas for ways to work around it, other than having a table that says you can't play more than N videos simultaneously on device X.